# Intermittent Azure Emulator Error: Could not load file or assembly 'XX' The filename or extension is too long.

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-caching

Using Visual Studio 2012 Premium SP1 11.051106.01 and Emulator version 1.8 I get the following error about ever 3-5 page refreshes.  I then have to stop debugging and re-deploy to the emulator.

I have at least 5 developers working on Azure and they all have the same problem when deploying Web Roles to an Azure Emulator.  My suspicion is that it has something to do with caching but I'm not sure where to start looking.

I've checked all my file path lengths and don't have any path and file names longer than 220 chars.  Win 7 has a maximum of 260 chars so I'm not sure what else to check.

Could not load file or assembly 'Kernel32' or one of its dependencies. The filename or extension is too long.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Web.dll' or one of its dependencies. The filename or extension is too long.

Comment: I face the same issue with two azure projects, currently I have only one azure project loaded and the other unloaded. Seemed so far not causing this issue anymore. Do you have any news what is casing this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when your temp path + solution is too long of a name.  There is a setting you can use to actually rebase the path and try to fix it.  Read about it here on [Jim's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/05/26/9942481.aspx).  Essentially, you set the _CSRUN_STATE_DIRECTORY environment variable to a shorter path.

Comment: Some fellow devs have tried this, but they still get the above error intermittently. I get it any time I run two cloud deployments side-by-side, even though I have my _CSRUN_STATE_DIRECTORY maped to C:\Z

Comment: Not sure why this got -1.  The error is not just jesting.  If it says your path is too long, it is too long.  Short of renaming your solution files, the answer I gave is accurate.